# @Input() Decorator and directives Angular-2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am new to angular2, I have 2 questions :-

**1.** I want to know why this is correct

```
<p myHighlight [color1]='color' defaultColor="violet">Highlight me!</p>
```

and these are not

```
<p myHighlight color1='color' defaultColor="violet">Highlight me!</p>

<p myHighlight [color1]='color' [defaultColor]="violet">Highlight me!</p>
```

Why i have to put only 1 property in brackets and the other without brackets.

**2.**  How can i use @Input() directive without aliasing in my code. does it work for multiple properties ?
Here is my directive code :

```
import { Input, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myHighlight]'
})
export class myDir {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Input('color1') color: string;//for ts code 'color' for html code 'myHighlight' i.e template component
    @Input('defaultColor') defaultColor: string;
    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        this.highlight(this.color || this.defaultColor);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        this.highlight(null);
    }

    private highlight(color: string) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

my html code :-

```
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="clr" (click)="color='lightgreen'">Green
    <input type="radio" name="clr" (click)="color='yellow'">Yellow
    <input type="radio" name="clr" (click)="color='cyan'">Cyan
</div>

<p myHighlight [color1]='color' [defaultColor]='violet'>Highlight me!</p>
```

Comment: ok so i just changed my code and without aliasing @input works if i have only 1 property.

Comment: Try this example application http://www.freakyjolly.com/example-app-share-data-between-angular-components-using-input-decorator/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First One

```
<p myHighlight color1='color' defaultColor="violet">Highlight me!</p>
```

color1 and default color are not attributes of paragraph tag so it will not work.

Second

```
<p myHighlight [color1]='color' [defaultColor]="violet">Highlight me!</p>
```

Your directive sets the color1 property to your paragraph tag and there is no violet variable in the component.

Everything inside `[ ]` are property bindings and those properties are represented using `@Input()` decorator.

Note:
**When you are using a component variable to bind property it should be in [ ]. If you are using direct value then you need not enclose in square brackets**

Comment: are you asking me something?

Comment: <p myHighlight [color1]='color' defaultColor="violet">Highlight me!</p> , here default color is not attribute but a property , so how is that working fine ? both color1 and defaultColor are properties, why they both require different syntax to be applied in this case

Comment: defaultColor is also a property and i bind it with @input, why it is wrong to use [defaultColor],

Comment: you can see the **directive code** the bg color  is applied with the color1 or defaultColor by toggling. Both color1 and defaultColor are assigned in the component(have a look at the component code)

Comment: i still dont get it , when both "color1" and "defaultColor" are my properties, why putting "defaultColor" in [] wont work ,                                                 i.e <p myHighlight [color1]='color' [defaultColor]='violet'>Highlight me!</p>

Comment: this is not working <p myHighlight [color1]='color' [defaultColor]='violet'>Highlight me!</p>
but this is working <p myHighlight [color1]='color' defaultColor='violet'>Highlight me!</p>

Comment: tell me this `violet` is a variable declared in the component??

Comment: i have added the code, now u can see i have used radio buttons to select color, and if no color is selected the default color is set

Comment: no violet is not a variable, it is a value that i have assigned in my template <p myHighlight [color1]='color' defaultColor='violet'>Highlight me!</p>

Comment: and you can see color is a variable declared in the component. check and tell

Comment: yes color is a variable, and violet is a value, so i just changed the code like [property]='variable' seems to work , but [property]='value' doesnot

Comment: when you are using a component variable to bind property it should be in `[ ]`. If you are using direct value then you need not enclose in square brackets got it?

Comment: Thanks man , now i get it, just edit your answer once again by adding the above answer in comment

Comment: done edited with main points please do mark as answer and upvote too

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[color]=" 'violet' "` would work though. (I added unnecessary space to ease reading)

Comment: Yes that's a string. But it's different from property binding